# How to add new input box when user want to input more data

Tags: javascript, php

my database have 2 table

1. college
2. course

college only store background of college like id, name, address and so on.
course have id from college and course1, course2 and ......

when college register to my system. they need to add their course..

### EXAMPLE

so how im gonna add this course if college AAA have 10 course. College BBB have 3 course
and college CCC have 15 course to add.. 
like

AAA

- it
- chef
- building
- design

BBB

- it
- chef

Comment: did i need to add more column if certain college have 30 course?

Comment: what you need?database stuff or javascript code, or u can put some code here to better understand.

Comment: so what have you started?

Comment: i dont know how to explain my question. i need a sample form how to add if certain college have huge course.. T-T

Comment: if you are looking for some javascript code then you can check my answer given below: may be it would help you.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you now have this DB structure:

```
[college]
id | name | course1 | course2 | ... | course10
```

It's wrong structure. Use pivot table for that.

```
[college_to_course]
college_id | course_id
```

And then to get all college courses you do

```
SELECT * FROM `college_to_course` WHERE `college_id` = 43246
```

---

In HTML/JS you simply create more fields for that:

```
<form>
  <?php foreach ($colleges $college): ?>
     <?php foreach ($college['courses'] as $course): ?>
         <input name="college_to_course[<?php echo $college['id']; ?>][]" />
     <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: i will try this method first before mark this as answer. from i start learning php and mysql. i did not know they have a pivot table. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are looking for some javascript code then here we go!!!

It is the working demo, how to add/remove multiple fields.
I hope this would help you.
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/aaki/hMJEy/1/

Comment: after that how to store to database. did i need 100 column for that? in case user want input 100 data? how about suddenly user want input 200 data? here im stuck. i dont know what table structre i want to use..

Comment: have you ever heard about implode() in php?? go for it.